# Print statements with each object in array Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop, printing

I can't seem to get each object to print when in the enhanced for loop. Any assistance would be appreciated. If I chose a specific worker object then the code would run fine but I just have it as worker[].fullName() and nothing is printing. Is there a way I can get it to print the respective worker each time it cycles through the loop? Thanks

```
package Persons;

public class InheritanceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Workers worker[] = new Workers[6];
         worker[0] = new Workers(25,"Tom", "Atkins", "4", "Mr.", 1992 );
         worker[1] = new Workers(28,"John", "Smith", "5", "Mr.", 1993 );
         worker[2] = new Workers(30,"Joe", "Doe", "6", "Mr.", 1980 );
         worker[3] = new SalaryWorker(50000,"Fawn", "Dawn", "7", "Mrs.", 1994 );
         worker[4] = new SalaryWorker(55000,"Clarence", "West", "8", "Mr.", 1986 );
         worker[5] = new SalaryWorker(60000,"Lucy", "Adams", "9", "Ms.", 1979 );

         for (Workers workers: worker){
             System.out.println("Week 1 pay period: "+ worker[].fullName());
             workers.calculateWeeklyPay(40);
             System.out.println("Week 2 pay period: ");
             workers.calculateWeeklyPay(50);
             System.out.println("Week 3 pay period: ");
             workers.calculateWeeklyPay(40);            
         }        
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to use `worker.fullName()`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I get a cannot find symbol error for the fullName() method

Comment: The class/variables are confusingly named (with the plurals). It should be `workers.fullName()` with the current code. The _correct_ thing to do, however, would be to have the class name (of the super class) in singular form, i.e. `Worker`. And the name of the array variable in plural, i.e. `Worker[] workers`. And then the loop becomes `for (Worker worker: workers)`.

Comment: @MickMnemonic thank you. That fixes my issue. I tried that before but I had the w in workers as capital which was just referring to the Workers class instead of the item in the loop. gracias gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think there is trouble with naming in for-each loop. You've interchanged `worker` & `workers`. 
Also `worker[].fullName()` is not acceptable construction. Correct is `worker.fullName()`
Please, try the code below:

```
for (Workers worker : workers) {
        System.out.println("Week 1 pay period: " + worker.fullName());
        worker.calculateWeeklyPay(40);
        System.out.println("Week 2 pay period: ");
        worker.calculateWeeklyPay(50);
        System.out.println("Week 3 pay period: ");
        worker.calculateWeeklyPay(40);
}
```

Comment: The name of the array is `worker`, so this won't compile.